# javascript closure: implicit parameters, caller

Tags: javascript, dom, closures, prototypal-inheritance

I need some clarification with javascript call's metadata. Provided code below has SenderAsParameterFunc and NoExplicitParametersFunc which are being called from AnotherFunction's each loops.

```
var Obj = function(){

Obj.SenderAsParameterFunc = function(sender, param1, param2){
// log $(sender).id;
}

Obj.NoExplicitParametersFunc = function(){

 // EXTRACT DEFAULT SENDER/CALLEE
 // I see in console Obj.NoExplicitParametersFunc.caller.arguments >> SEE REF1
}

 Obj.NoExplicitParametersFuncWithExtraArgs = function(this, par1, par2){
 // 'this' from each loop?
}

Obj.AnotherFunc = function(){

    var X = $('myselect');

    var par1 = 1;
    var par2 = 'bla';
    $.each(X.find("option"), function () {
                Obj.SenderAsParameterFunc(this, par1, par2); 
                // 'this' here references current object from 'each' loop
            });

    $.each(X.find("option"), Obj.NoExplicitParametersFunc); 
   // must be equvalent to first var, 
   // but to extract 'inner' this we have to do more magic in NoExplicitParametersFunc...

    var par1 = 1;
    var par2 = 'bla';
    $.each(X.find("option"), Obj.NoExplicitParametersFuncWithExtraArgs);
    }

}
```

So WHAT should be written in NoExplicitParametersFunc to get access to each option as that is done in SenderAsParameterFunc with $(this)?

==========

OK, TO Summarize what I've learned:
if a function goes without parameters

```
$.each(X.find("option"), Obj.NoExplicitParametersFunc);
```

then 'this' is passed by default and is accessible within a function.

If a function has parameters

```
$.each(X.find("option"), function () { Obj.SenderAsParameterFunc(this, par1, par2); });
```

then 'this' MUST be included as a parameter (first?) to be accessible within the function.

=============

REF1:

```
b.Event
altKey: undefined
attrChange: undefined
attrName: undefined
bubbles: true
cancelable: false
ctrlKey: undefined
currentTarget: input#inputId
data: undefined
delegateTarget: input#inputId
eventPhase: 2
handleObj: Object
isDefaultPrevented: function ot(){return!1}
jQuery19105656534675508738: true
metaKey: false
originalEvent: Event
relatedNode: undefined
relatedTarget: undefined
shiftKey: undefined
srcElement: input#inputId
target: input#inputId
timeStamp: 1366622725473
type: "change"
view: undefined
which: undefined
__proto__: Object,
```

currentTarget, delegateTarget, srcElement, target ARE same, but what should be actually used, the most correct way? References would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: the `REF1` does not look like a result of your provided code. it is a jQuery event object.

Comment: WTH is `Obj.caller.arguments` supposed to be?

Comment: It's Obj.NoExplicitParametersFunc.caller.arguments, if it doesn't suppose to do anything, then let's pay attention on what can and will to something.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $.each(X.find("option"), function () {
>       Obj.SenderAsParameterFunc(this);
>       // 'this' here references anonymous function, 
>       // from which it was called, so 'this' is sender
> });
> ```

No. The *anonymous* function is not referenced by anything here (it is accessible as a parameter only in `$.each`). The [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in the callbacks of [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) does reference the iterated items. That also does answer your question:

```
Obj.NoExplicitParametersFunc = function(i, v){
    console.log(this, i, v);
}
```

> If a function has parameters [and is called in an anonymous function expression] then 'this' MUST be included as a parameter (first?) to be accessible within the function.

Yes, as `this` is unique to each function call you have to pass its value along - just like you cannot just access local variables of your caller function, you cannot access its `this` value. To call the function with a specific this-value, you can use [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
$.each(X.find("option"), function(i, v) {
    Obj.SenderAsParameterFunc.call(this, i, v, par1, par2);
});
```

Comment: in console.log(this, i, v); this === Obj

Comment: Not if you call it with `$.each(X.find("option"), Obj.NoExplicitParametersFunc);` - did you read the MDN introduction to `this` which I linked?

Comment: the link was not obvious and it is not subtle enough, doesn't address the problem precisely. Will the local parameters with the same names be sent to the function as well? $.each(X.find("option"), Obj.NoExplicitParametersFunc);

Comment: What do you mean by "local parameters"? Those `par1` and `par2` variables in your updated example code will never be accessible from the `Obj.NoExplicitParametersFunc` function - you can only pass their values along the function call.

Comment: Please check summarization in the middle of the post

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** In your case it doesn't matter, but if you are in doubt use `currentTarget`

---

I don't really understand your first question, but about the second one...

When an event is dispatched usually this event bubbles, for example on this page:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="foobar.png" />
  </div>
</body>
```

If the user clicks a `img` element inside a `div` it will fire the events this way

```
body - capturing
div - capturing
img - at target
div - bubbling
body - bubbling
```

So you can add a listener to `body` and you'll catch the event. But to allow you to know which element was ACTUALLY clicked (the `img` in this case) it provides `event.target` property (`srcElement` on Internet Explorer).

`delegateTarget` is a property added by jQuery and it provides extra info if you use event delegation. I don't know exactly what it is but you can take a look [at the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/)

And finally `currentTarget` is the element you attached the event, if we added the listener to `body` it'll be `body`. So the arguments on each events are

```
fire body.click with { target: img, currentTarget: body }
fire div.click  with { target: img, currentTarget: div  }
fire img.click  with { target: img, currentTarget: img  }
fire div.click  with { target: img, currentTarget: div  }
fire body.click with { target: img, currentTarget: body }
```

Depending on what you are doing you will need one or the other property.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Please check the "Summarize" section in the middle of updated post.. probably I just got confused about obvious things. Thanks.